# Dell DRAC console sessions won't time out

Tags: remote-access, dell, dell-poweredge, drac

I've got a Dell DRAC 5 card connected to a PowerEdge 2900. I've used the console redirect successfully before, but presently the "console redirection" section shows "Active Sessions" = 2, so it won't allow any more console redirection sessions.

I haven't used the remote access console in months, so I'm confident that it's just "stuck" thinking that old sessions are still active. Any suggestions on how to force them to time out, or perhaps forcibly "reboot" just the DRAC card? I'm reluctant to reboot the server, as it's a production server and I'd need to be on-site in the middle of the night in order to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the racreset command, this may be available from your OS if you have the OMSA packages installed or you may have to ssh directly the DRAC (assuming it will let you do that).

This will reset the DRAC (taking it offline briefly).

See - http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/drac4/1.1/en/ug/racugaa.htm#wp31217

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the correct answer. Because this was a DRAC 5 card, the full command is "racadm racreset"